# "Azure File Copy" task failing for copying files to VM

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, vnext

I have looking for ways to update a web api deployed on Azure VM's using TFS vNext. The Web Api is deployed on multiple Azure Virtual Machines (classic).

I am using the "Azure File Copy" task to copy the published websites to the relevant folder on the virtual machines.

[image]

The build goes to upload files from local file path to blob fine but after that fails with the following error

```
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1524432Z ##[error], ServiceCommandException\r\n FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand\r\n"}};]
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1674435Z ##[warning]'##vso[task.logissue type=error;code={"Task_Internal_Error":Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c'. Consult the logs below:' contains logging command keyword '##vso', but it's not a legal command. Please reference documentaion to fix any potentially syntax error (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1684427Z ##vso[task.logissue type=error;code={"Task_Internal_Error":Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c'. Consult the logs below:
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1684427Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c on computer '.'.
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1684427Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1684427Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2017-04-11T10:54:53.1684427Z  For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme};]
2017-04-11T10:54:53.3654455Z ##[error]Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c'. Consult the logs below:
Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer28cc825e-0ecd-4362-a597-7ff9a10b7f2c on computer '.'.
 CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Comment: Is the machine configured to allow WinRM connections? Did you review the documentation? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/README.md

Comment: What's the version of your TFS? Can you copy files to Azure VM by using AzCopy command-line? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#file-upload)

Comment: The machine was allowed to make WinRM connection and we are using TFS 2017 Update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue. It was invalid credentials that was causing the error. I was using the login of "admin login" with the machine name. When I used only the login part of the name, it worked fine.

Comment: What you mean 'login part of the name' ?